# Angular component resolve binding is defined

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a controller that instantiates a `Restangular` object.

```
Restangular.one('doctors', profile_id).get().then(function(resp) {
  $scope.doctor = resp;
})
```

I also have a component that would like to wait for $scope.doctor to be defined before it is instantiated. How can I ensure doctor is defined?

```
app.component('doctorReviews', {
  bindings: {
    doctor: '='
  },
  controller: function() {

    var self = this;

    this.doctor.getList('reviews').then(function(resp) {
      self.reviews = _.sortBy(resp, 'separation')
    })

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add `ng-if='doctor != null'` in your page template to ensure `doctorReviews` initialized after `doctor` defined:

```
//somewhere in your page html...
<doctor-reviews ng-if='doctor != null'></doctor-reviews>
```